# Output from beanstalkd

Tags: beanstalkd

I want to monitor what jobs are flowing through a beanstalkd queue. Is there a way I can do this through command line. On running beanstalkd on command line no output is displayed. Essentially I am looking for a debug or a verbose option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

beanstalkd doesn't ship with any management tools as far as I know.  But if you install one of the python/ruby/perl libraries you can write something to emit server status pretty easily.

Here's an example using python and the beanstalkc client package:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                           

import beanstalkc

b = beanstalkc.Connection(host='localhost', port=11300)
for tube in b.tubes():
    print "Tube: %s" % tube
    stats = b.stats_tube(tube)
    for k, v in stats.items():
        print "   %s: %s" % (k, v)
```